# Do not wrap custom block in an additional DIV but instead use only the JSX I provide

Tags: block-editor

When registering new blocks, on front-end I get only the markup that I specify inside of `save` method. Cool! That's what I need.
But when using the `edit` method I get my markup wrapped in a `div`. That's not what I need, because it limits my possibilities of styling.

How can I get rid of that div and have it similar to what the current core/paragraph block does, for example, with the `p` tag?

---

**Here is how I have it now:**

[image]

**and that's how it should become:**
[image]

For reference the code is simple like this:

```
edit: () => {
    return (
        <span className="sample-block">
            <mark>Sample</mark>
        </span>
    );
},
save: () => {
    return (
        <span className="sample-block">
            <mark>Sample</mark>
        </span>
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** WordPress 5.6 will be released soon and this will include a block API version 2 which allows all these modifications noted in OP.
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/

---

I found a filter that allows me to modify the wrapper. Still, I can't change the HTML tag, but it's better than nothing.

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;

const withClientIdClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const newClassName = "block-" + props.clientId + ' sample-block';
        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ newClassName } />;
    };
}, 'withClientIdClassName' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'awps/modify-blocks-wrapper', withClientIdClassName );
```

And the methods:

```
edit: () => {
    return (
        <mark>Sample</mark>
    );
},
save: () => {
    return (
        <span className="sample-block">
            <mark>Sample</mark>
        </span>
    );
},
```